# redux-form asyncValidation value undefined

Tags: redux-form

I have setup a asyncValidation for my redux-form. I just figured out, that the changed field always is undefined in the values object that gets passed to the asyncValidate function.

Lets say i change the field firstname from "abc" to "abcd" everything works and the state gets updated. I get the following actions: (redux-form/)FOCUS, CHANGE, BLUR, START_ASYNC_VALIDATION and STOP_ASYNC_VALIDATION.
However, in the asyncValidate function:

```
  handledAsyncValidate = values => {
    console.log('values', values) 
  }
```

Directly after the change i get: {firstname: undefined, lastname: ''}
But when i trigger an asyncValidation on lastname, firstname is defined with "abcd".

Im using redux-form 6.5. Is there a change i have implemented something the wrong way? I dont use asyncValidateFields but i tested it and it does not change the described effect.

**Edit:**

Its a fairly large codebase. 
Here i create my asyncValidation function and pass it to the form:
https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/pr/entity-browser/form-refactoring/packages/entity-browser/src/routes/detail/components/DetailView/DetailView.js

When i log values there, the changed field will be undefined.

The form you can find here:

https://github.com/tocco/tocco-client/blob/pr/entity-browser/form-refactoring/packages/entity-browser/src/routes/detail/components/DetailForm/DetailForm.js

More than happy so help you find something specific.

Comment: Please add the full code for your form.

Comment: Yes, we need more code to help you.

Comment: i added a link to the repo

Comment: i still have this issue. anyone experience the same behavior?

Comment: @MethodenMann did you ever figure out what was causing this?